# load model in another modules in hmvc in codeigniter 3.0 not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

i am trying to load model of one module in another module in CI 3.

it's working in < 3 version like this

> $this->load->model("module01/models01");

but, in CI 3 is not working like the same
[image]

you can see the structure and my controller code here.

help to resolve it,

thanks

Comment: can you share what error you getting?

Comment: I think it is because of your folder structure. As you have defined modules in capital letters. Try to make module name in small letters.
e.g. a_company, a_product
then check. may be it will work.